# Update Clarity Seed Project

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I've started developing an Angular 4 application using Clariy.
I've started the project cloning the Clarity seed project, and with that base, I've started building my components.

How can I update Clarity to the last version? I would like to keep Clarity updated as musch as I can while I'm developing the product.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you update the Clarity version in the [Clarity package.json](https://github.com/vmware/clarity-seed/blob/master/package.json#L25) to the Clarity version you want to install as James said aove all you have to do is run `npm install` and the package will update. Note, there are three Clarity libraries to update in the seed project:

1. [@clr/angular](https://github.com/vmware/clarity-seed/blob/master/package.json#L25) or [clarity-angular](https://github.com/vmware/clarity-seed/blob/master/package.json#L25) if you are before 0.11
2. [@clr/ui](https://github.com/vmware/clarity-seed/blob/master/package.json#L27) or [clarity-ui](https://github.com/vmware/clarity-seed/blob/master/package.json#L27) if you are before 0.11
3. [@clr/icons](https://github.com/vmware/clarity-seed/blob/master/package.json#L26) or [clarity-icons](https://github.com/vmware/clarity-seed/blob/master/package.json#L26) if you are before 0.11

You can see the latest version (as well as what has changed) on our documentation site [here](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/news).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Clarity specifically but assuming it is an NPM Package, then you can run `npm update` to update all of your packages or `npm update clarity` to update clarity specifically.

Comment: The package name is not `clarity`